# How to make getA1Notation & setName work together?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I've got the following script, I am using lastRow and lastColum to create a var lastCell (`sh.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn();`), I am then trying to rename a sheet to match that value. As it's a string, I know I have to use getA1Notation, so I have tried `var SheetName = last.Cell.getA1Notation();` and then a `setName(SheetName)` however that doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Any ideas why?

```
function onSubmit(e){
  var ss = e.source;
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sh.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var col = sh.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();
  var activeRange = sh.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sh.getLastColumn();
  var lastCell = sh.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);
  var SheetName = lastCell.getA1Notation();

  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet(1, {template: templateSheet});
  newSheet.setName(SheetName);
  newSheet.showSheet();
  newSheet.appendRow(e.values);
```

Comment: 'As it's a string, I know I have to use getA1Notation, ' is a false notion.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `onSubmit` trigger only runs when a form is submitted. You cannot run it from the context of the editor. If you change it to a generic function and run the script, it works as you described, setting the new name to the A1 notation of the last cell on the page.

If you wanted the value *of* the cell, you're not getting the value of anything. For `SheetName`, you're only getting the cell position with `.getA1Notation`. If you want the value inside the cell, change it to:

```js
var lastCell = sh.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);  // get the cell
var SheetName = lastCell.getValue();              // return the string value
```

Setting that string will now rename the new sheet you created to the value in the cell.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your help! I'm using on Form Submit as I have a test form I am working on and the final version will also use a form. I have changed SheetName to reflect your suggestion as above, but it create's the new sheet with the name 'Copy of Template'

Comment: I just replicated your setup and it ran successfully. [Open this copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q7HpDk2cT35CoOzsbr9rk-ADfsFk0nQA08eGPeIkw6Y/copy) and try running to compare with your version. The associated form should also be copied when you save it to your Drive.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for this (I have been away on holiday, sorry for not replying sooner!). The form didnt replicate so I paired it up with one. It's still not working for me.I am using another colum (after the URL) with the following formula `=iferror(arrayformula(proper(index(split(A2:A,".@"),0,1)&" "&index(split(A2:A,".@"),0,2))))` which takes the email address and splits it into First and Second name. This is ideally what I would like to use for the naming of the file.